# Rounded numbers for y-Axis labels in Core-Plot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I have a graph area where I can choose to plot different attributes. Each attribute defines its own y-Axis range. The following image shows the y-Axis labels which are rounded to the nearest unit (does not look clean).

[image: Plots]

What can I do so that the y-Axis labels are rounded to the nearest millionth, thousandth, or hundredth in accordance with the data being graphed?

I also thought that I could set the lower and upper limits of the y-Axis to those rounded numbers so that I can later set an even increment that will give me those better-looking labels. How can I get those rounded limits?

What I am doing right now to set those limits is the following:

```
    //Look up the absolute minimum and absolute maximum values
    NSNumber * min = [allArraysDrawn valueForKeyPath:@"@min.intValue"];
    NSNumber * max = [allArraysDrawn valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"];
    //Define the limits of the plot area with a cushion both above the max value and below the min value
    float yAxisMin = [min floatValue] - (([max floatValue] - [min floatValue]) * 0.05);
    float yAxisMax = [max floatValue] + (([max floatValue] - [min floatValue]) * 0.05);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic` axis labeling policy. It will compute "nice" intervals for the tick marks and grid lines. If that isn't satisfactory, use the default `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval` labeling policy and choose a `majorIntervalLength` that is the desired power of ten.

Comment: Is there a labeling policy that can shorten the numbers if they are too large? For example: `20k for 20,000`, or `3M for 3,000,000`?

Comment: You can set up the `labelFormatter` to do this. `NSNumberFormatter` has lots of options.

Comment: @EricSkroch I am not using core-plot but can you explain or show logic behind it? It would really help.

Comment: Core Plot's code for "nice" numbers is [here](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/framework/Source/CPTAxis.m#L1228).

Comment: @EricSkroch Yeah that really works. Is that file having finding number of nice intervals between two min and max values?

Comment: No, the `niceLength` function is used for that.

Comment: @EricSkroch So if I pass max value it will gives the number of nice fixed intervals?

Comment: No, it will calculate a "nice" number near the max. It's up to you how many intervals to use. You should also look at the `-autoGenerateMajorTickLocations:minorTickLocations:` method in that same file to see how we calculate the divisions based on a range (starting location and length).

Comment: @EricSkroch I just checked NiceLength() method return less than or equal to max rounded value.What if i want to do reverse like greater or equal to max rounded value?

Comment: Change `NSRoundDown` to `NSRoundUp`.